# Восстановление файла через дамп процесса

Tags: linux, восстановление, dump, recovery

Имеется дамп процесса internet explorer, в котором был открыт текстовый файл. Файл был удалён с ПК, браузер не закрывался. Каким образом можно восстановить текстовый файл или узнать его содержимое?

Comment: можешь скормить дамп в `strings` и поискать в выводе нечто похожее на твой текстовый файл…

Comment: Уже пытался. Находит только его название, но не более. Других вариантов нет?

Comment: варианты типа `strings -e S ... | iconv -f cp1251` или `strings -e S ... | while read line; do echo $line | enca; done` и `strings -e l ...` тоже пробовал?

Comment: Нет, сейчас попробую